# Booting Ubuntu causes LAN to stop working in Ubuntu and Windows until BIOS reset

Tags: networking, lubuntu, bios, lan

I've just installed Lubuntu 17.04 alongside Windows 7

When I run Lubuntu then the port does not work, the indicators are not lit, nothing at all, and I cannot connect.

When I restart the PC on Windows, the same situation happens; the network card does not work no signs of life (although in fact everything is fine-tuned, and was working before I installed Linux)

I found the solution to the problem was to pull out the PC and do a BIOS reset (clrcmos).

When I start Windows everything works, everything is as usual, and when I run Linux, everything will repeat.

This problem was observed in other Linux distributions (Ubuntu, Linux Mint).

What can the problem can be and how it can be solved?

Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-H81-D3 rev.2.0 
CPU: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G3220 @ 3.00GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti 
RAM: 8,00 GB 
LAN: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller (RTL8167) 
 
BIOS: FB. date: 07/31/14 Ver: 04.06.05

Comment: Since the problem seems to be BIOS related, try a BIOS update, if available. Generally, Ubuntu is not known to break LAN cards, or modify BIOS.

Comment: You can try a power reset of the host.  Pull all the power from the computer and press the power button a few times with no power.  Then plug the power back in and see if that resets the board.  If not, you could be looking at a bad board.

Comment: I also think that Ubuntu should not change anything in BIOS, but the result is that when he installed various Windows (7, 8, 10) everything was fine, he installed Debian 6, 7, too, everything is quite distinct, but in Ubuntu since 16.04 appeared such a problem

Comment: maybe this is related to UEFI (boot mode)?

Comment: Please give details of your hardware - the network cards and make & model of PC

Comment: @Terrance thanks for the help, I do not know why or how, but it works
I turned off the PC, disconnected from the power, pressed the Power button several times, and then turned on Lubuntu and about the miracle, everything works, and Windows also sees Lan Port
Thanks you
but here's just one question, how is this related?
what was the problem?

Comment: I don't really know what the problem was.  What I do know is that there are capacitors on the motherboard that can store power and be slowly drained when the computer is turned off.  However, this power can also lead to memory being stored.  For whatever reason, the network card might have turned off and the memory was storing that.  This has become a valid fix in the data center I work in, as well as way back in the late 90s when I was working in a tech shop.  It really had nothing to do with the software, but more with the hardware.  I had to reset my board last night due to slow uploads.

Comment: @Terrance
 thank you very much, you really helped)
I spent a long time struggling with this problem and could not work properly

Comment: Glad I could help and that it is working now!  =)

Comment: @Zanna
Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-H81-D3 rev.2.0
CPU: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G3220 @ 3.00GHz
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti
RAM: 8,00 GB
LAN: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller (RTL8167)
BIOS: FB. date: 07/31/14 Ver: 04.06.05

for my BIOS there is a new version, do you think it's worth updating?

Comment: @Terrance if you would post that as an answer, I would definitely upvote it (users won't know it's a hardware issue, so it will help many people who come here thinking it's a software issue)

Comment: BTW Vlad Gudym please add that information to your question rather than posting it in a comment :) I can't give you any useful advice on BIOS updates, but if you update your question, others might be able to :)

Comment: If the accepted answer doesn't actually solve the issue I suggest you (1) try a newer kernel with newer firmware and try again and, if that fails, (2) file a bug report against the kernel because it's likely a bug in either the kernel driver or the device firmware or the BIOS in which case the kernel developers can figure report it to the manufacturer for a fix or provide a work-around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are experiencing this problem in two different operating systems, it could be a hardware issue with the network card.  Try performing a power reset or [hard reset](https://www.google.com/search?q=PC+Power+Reset+procedure&oq=PC+Power+Reset+procedure&aqs=chrome..69i57.6427j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) on the system.

The following steps are how to perform the reset:

1. Shut down the computer.
2. Remove all power from the computer.  (If it is a laptop, remove the battery)
3. With all power removed, press the power button and hold it for 15 seconds, or press it a few times in a row.
4. Connect power back to the computer and power it back on.

If this procedure does not work it could be an actual hardware failure and needs to be replaced.

This procedure can work with fixing computers that will not power on, network cards running slow, hard drives not being detected, etc.  Motherboards have capacitors on them that store power.   The slow power drain from capacitors can keep power going to other parts of the motherboard keeping memory in them when the computer is powered off.  Pulling the power and pressing the power button will cause the motherboard itself to try to power back on.  This causes all the capacitors to be drained thus clearing any memory stored.

Hope this helps!