# Internet is really slow on wired connection

Tags: networking, upgrade, internet, dns, 17.10

I've been using Ubuntu 16.10 for about one year, and recently I upgraded to `17.04`. After upgrade, the internet didn't work. I modified the `/etc/resolv.conf` file adding the Google's DNS ip:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 8.8.8.8 # This is what I added
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

Then the internet worked again, but a little bit slower.
I successfully upgraded to `17.10` without problems, but the speed feels much slower, and in fact it is:

```
$ speed-test 

      Ping   3600 ms
  Download   2.9 Mbps
    Upload   1.6 Mbps
```

On devices connected via wifi I have ~20 Mbps. I assume it's because of the upgrade, but I have no idea what could cause the slowness.

Sometimes, in the browser accessing some websites often fails with DNS related errors. It happens randomly.

How to fix this?

Comment: I have experienced where a 1Gb connection was very slow and power resetting my system worked:  https://askubuntu.com/a/962832/231142  Try that one out and see.

Comment: @Terrance I'm afraid I cannot really open my laptop right now to take the battery out of it... Isn't there an easier? :D Thanks!

Comment: Try the same procedure, but hold down the power button for at least 15 seconds due to the battery being sealed.  Make sure to remove any USB devices and AC Adapters.

Comment: @Terrance I did this procedure. Restarted. What I noticed is that it's fast (`45Mbps`) only when the *Chromium* browser is **not** open... Not sure what is wrong with Chromium... When I start Chromium, the internet goes down for few seconds, then works again, then goes down again. Thanks for help!

Comment: Hmmm, not sure why Chromium would be causing a slow down like that.  Maybe ask a new question about Chromium.  I use Firefox and Chrome so I might not be much help with Chromium.  Glad that you do have fast speeds again.  :)