# Ubuntu 17.10 slow LAN copy speed

Tags: lan, wired

Following an upgrade from 17.04 --> 17.10 my network copy speed for a file from 1 Ubuntu machine to another has slowed to 10% of what it was before the upgrade.

A 1 gB file now takes over an hour to copy between the two machines instead of a couple of minutes.

If I initiate the same copy from a windows PC, copying the same file between the same 2 Ubuntu machines the copy completes in a couple of minutes as expected.

I'm not even sure where to start to diagnose this issue as clearly both underlying networking setups must be correct if the windows machine can copy the file quickly??

After some more investigation Gnome Commander and cp (from the command line) copy fast whilst nautilus/thunar & gcp copy slow.

*****@*****:~$ cp '/****/****/*****/*****/*****' '/*****/****/*****/*****' 
10 files (699.2 MiB) copied in 122.0 seconds (  5.7 MiB/s).

*****@*****:~$ gcp -r '/****/****/*****/*****/*****' '/*****/****/*****/*****' 
Copying 699.15 MiB 100% |############################|   1.73 MB/s Time: 0:07:03

Comment: How do you copy the file(s)? What is your network?

Comment: vidarlo - smb share on the Ubuntu file server mounted at boot vis fstab on the Ubuntu client.

Comment: What is the speed from the command 'ethtool eno1'?  Going from 1Gbs to 100Mbs is 10%, it could be from changing a switch, network card, bad cable, etc

Comment: rtaft 1 nic is 100mbs and there is also a LAN segment at 100 mbs.  Good speeds are 5 - 13 mB/s bad speeds are 100 - 500kB/s.

Comment: Honestly, try the power reset procedure.  You have nothing to lose by trying it.  I work around thousands of systems everyday and we have seen this sooooo many times I have lost count.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/962618/booting-ubuntu-causes-lan-to-stop-working-in-ubuntu-and-windows-until-bios-reset and https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/h/hardrese.htm

Comment: I've tried the power reset procedure now on both machines and It hasn't helped.  Interestingly copying from the server to the client is still fast. (5 - 13 mB/s)

Comment: Check disk read speed, how fast is this 'dd if=<your 1GB file> of=/dev/null'?

Comment: rtaft - results of disk read speed  -  
1430580+0 records in
1430580+0 records out
732456960 bytes (732 MB, 699 MiB) copied, 9.1054 s, 80.4 MB/s  Is there a similar command to test disk write speed?  as it is writing to the server from the client that is slow?  but using a win10 pc to handle the copy is fast so unlikely to be disk write speed.

Comment: Ubuntu server (desktop as file server) is 16.04 LTS client is 17.10  since the issue arose following upgrading the client to 17.10 could it be something to do with the smb implementations of these two versions?  Although nothing I can think of explains why copying with Win10 between the 2 machines works.

Comment: Are the scp speeds between the 2 ubuntu boxes normal?

Comment: no idea, just use smb with password authentication...  Is there a preferred app / implementation of secure copy over ssh for me to test?

Comment: Are you using a 10/100Mb hub between the systems?  Or a 10/100Mb switch between the systems?  A hub can transfer packets blindly to every port causing unnecessary network overhead, where a switch acts as a traffic cop and sends the packets to the port that matches the destination(s).

Comment: It's a slightly more complicated setup than that...  the path between the two machines is...  Ubuntu 17.10 PC --> DDWRT router(gbs) --> Powerline (in) (100mbs) --> Powerline (100mbs)(out) --> Gb switch --> Ubuntu 16.04 PC.  This setup worked before the upgrade to 17.10.

Comment: After some more investigation I installed advanced copy and gcp.  Advasnced copy (and cp) from the commandline both seem to copy fast whilst gcp seems to copy at a simelar speed to nautilus.  Gnome Commander also seems to copy fast although has no speed indicator.                 *****@*****:~$ cp '/****/****/*****/*****/*****' '/*****/****/*****/*****' 
10 files (699.2 MiB) copied in 122.0 seconds (  5.7 MiB/s).

       *****@*****:~$ gcp -r '/****/****/*****/*****/*****' '/*****/****/*****/*****' 
Copying 699.15 MiB 100% |############################|   1.73 MB/s Time: 0:07:03