# Ubuntu does not boot up at all, not even to grub - completely black sceeen

Tags: 18.04

The screen is completely black (previously it would be black but lit up black until the vendor logo came on). I have tried Esc, both Shifts, Ctrl+Alt+F(1-7).

The light on the side of my machine does come on when I press the power button so I assume this is a visual display issue only. But without being able to see anything I cannot get to grub, cannot get to a terminal, and don't see what my options are.

I have also tried booting from an Ubuntu Live USB, but same issue, without being able to see I have no idea how to start to debug and sort.

It is not an Nvidia card, the laptop is an Entroware Apollo (Graphics card Intel® UHD Graphics).

My laptop was freezing every so often so I tried switching to lightdm to see if it would solve. Loaded up fine and continued for a bit, but first time it froze again, in reboot, the completely black screen occurred.

Hope someone has some ideas! If any more details would be useful please let me know.

Comment: Maybe try doing a power reset:  https://askubuntu.com/a/962832/231142  If the battery is non-removable try holding in the power button for 30 seconds.

Comment: Any chance of hooking up a tv or second monitor?

Comment: Yes I tried hooking it up to a monitor via HDMI, but the monitor says no signal unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the power suggestion as well. No luck though unfortunately. I cannot remove the battery but it did drain down fully and after plugging it in again still nothing. Holing for 30 seconds also doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: The system might have gone belly up.  If you are not getting anything on the screen nor on an external screen there is nothing that you or we can do to help.  Maybe take it to a tech shop or look up if there is a reset procedure online for your laptop.

Comment: Okay thank you! Contacted Entroware support, will update if they reply with a solution (which I suppose is likely sending it in)

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot get into boot options / BIOS / UEFI, it's likely a hardware issue.

Comment: Do you have a ctrl key for turning your laptop display on and off ? Usually a white square symbol on one of the F keys on Lenovo laptops for example. Also, I agree with needing to know if you see the BIOS screen at switch on

Comment: Nope unfortunately I cannot get to the BIOS in any way - completely black from the start.

Comment: Yes I have a display on and off key via a Fn button but this does nothing unfortunately.

Comment: I know it is turning on still as the keyboard pills back-lights do light up as well. Not sure if that is useful info.

Answer (score 0):

If you can hear the hdd revving up and the keyboard back-lights are on then most likely the LCD panel is gone. If you have a auxiliary vga or hdmi port try connecting an external monitor/tv and see whether you can get the display going.

Answer (score 0):

if your confident opening your machine up try clearing your CMOS by removing the little battery for a few minutes then replacing it. make sure machine is unplugged! and earth yourself.