# Ubuntu 16.04 Server: Battery is always 0% and laptop turns off when unplugged. Also battery voltage is ~12V

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery

I have an old laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 Server. A week ago I noticed strange shutdowns happening. As no software problem was discovered, I discussed the problem with a local hardware specialist who confirmed that the battery is "dead". I bought a new battery, set it up and now the laptop works normally when AC Adapter is plugged in. When I unplug it, though, the laptop turns off immediately. UPower detects the battery's manufacturer, capacity, voltage (which is usually around 12V and is constantly changing)  but for "energy", "energy-empty", "energy-rate" and "percentage" it always returns "0". Also, the battery is detected as BAT1 (instead of BAT0). What could the problem be and how to solve it? The new battery clearly charges up, but cannot support the laptop autonomously (without the AC adapter plugged in).

Comment: Try maybe doing a hard power cycle of your laptop and see if that helps.  https://askubuntu.com/a/962832/231142  Did the hardware specialist confirm if the charging circuit in the laptop was functioning normal?  This does not sound like a software issue but a hardware issue.

Comment: Tried to do the hard power cycle, but the result remains the same. The hardware specialist did not confirm a working charging circuit, do this must be the problem, I will bring the laptop to him tomorrow.